# How to send users to a new web page based off of text input object

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a text adventure game. In it, the user types a command in a text input box. Based on the command, they will be sent to another web page. Here's what I have for HTML:

`<input type="text" id="a" onchange="text()" value=""/>`

Here's what I have for javascript:

```
function text(){
    var input = document.getElementById("a").value;

    switch(input){
        case "run":
            window.location.replace("1_2.html");
        case "rescue":
            window.location.replace("1_3.html");
    }
}
```

But, if they type run or rescue, it sends them to 1_3.html. I have tried switching `window.location.replace` with `window.location.href` but they are not taken to 1_3.html nor 1_2.html. I have also tried using `if else if else` but it gets the same results and problems. What should I do?

Comment: need the break; to stop the switch after the first case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like

```
function text(){
    var input = document.getElementById("a").value;

    switch(input.toLowerCase()){
        case "run":
            window.location.replace("1_2.html");break;
        case "rescue":
            window.location.replace("1_3.html");break;
    }
}
```

Because your input may contain upper and Lower case

Answer (score 2):

See the correct syntax for a switch statement

```
function text(){
    var input = document.getElementById("a").value;

    switch(input){
        case "run":
            window.location.replace("1_2.html");
            break;
        case "rescue":
            window.location.replace("1_3.html");
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Default case");
    }
}
```

If you omit the break statement, the next case will be executed even if the evaluation does not match the case (from w3schools)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like
Add `Break;` after `Cases`

```
case "run":
    window.location.replace("1_2.html");break;
case "rescue":
    window.location.replace("1_3.html");break;
```